# Making an Angular Service to Maintain a counter

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-services

I am trying to experiment with angular services. As a test I wanted to make a simple counter which incremented across multiple controllers and throughout the browser life cycle. My service seems to be re-initialized in each controller, any ideas ?

**NOTE: Controllers are on different pages - so there is a page reload**

```
angular.module('myApp').service('Session', function($http) {

    this.inc = function() {
        console.log("INC Called and Global is :" + this.count);
        if(this.count) {
            this.count++;
        } else {
            this.count = 0;
        }

   };

    this.get = function() {
        return this.count;
    };

});
```

And then in the controller I call

```
Session.inc();
```

and

```
Session.get();
```

Comment: I think issue is `this` inside a function is not the `this` present in your service function..

Comment: tried var self = this, does not solve the problem self.count is still undefined each time

Comment: may be try injecting $rootScope and update the use $rootScope.counter value for incrementing inside your service, get the same value in controller by using rootscope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is ok, but your logic is wrong:

```
   this.inc = function() {
        console.log("INC Called and Global is :" + this.count);
        if(this.count) {
            this.count++;
        } else {
            this.count = 0;
        }

   };
```

First time it's ran, `this.count` will be initialized to `0` which will evaluate to false every next time. Change it to:

```
 this.count = 0;
 this.inc = function() {
    this.count++;
 };
```

Much more understandable.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/WoPVQZuzQ7Ow781OOgtj?p=preview

#### Edit: It seems that author is trying to maintain service state over page changes. In order to do that, you can use localstorage:

```
 this.count = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0;
 this.inc = function() {
    this.count++;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', this.count);
 };
```

Comment: my first attempt was as you suggested - but count was always initialized to 0. I.e each time the service was consumed by a controller

Comment: @avrono You're doing something else wrong buddy, I've added a plnkr demo in my answer.

Comment: what about for two controllers. I am going exactly what you are , it's the second controller , i.e I navigate from one page to another with a different controller - I would expect the service to maintain state

Comment: After full page reload? Nope, service can't maintain state over page reloads.

Comment: Ok, that would explain it then :-)

Comment: thanks, works - would you use this to store session variables ?

Comment: I wouldn't store anything considered a security risk (e.g. session ID, session name, etc.) inside localStorage

Comment: @jusopi what would you use for my scenario above ?

Comment: You might store the user name and a session token via cookies or local storage, your login service would then determine if that session token had expired, if so, require another login. But never a password.